# Join 2 collections in mongo with a where clause

Tags: database, mongodb, join

I am trying to join two collections, products and images, it works fine without clause but I want to be able to put one for example: find all products and images filtering by products _id, I have tried the below code but I am getting an empty array as result from the DB, any help would be appreciated.

```
    try{
        const join = await Products.aggregate([
            { "$match": { "_id": "5c128942415f3f0d8303764e" }},
            { $lookup: {
                from: "images",
                localField: "_id",
                foreignField: "productID",
                as: "pictures"
            }
        }
    ]);
    res.send(join)
    }
```

Comment: Yeah looks like it was that! thanks